# Midtown Madness 2, a DirectX 7.0a game, runs slow on Windows 8

Tags: backwards-compatibility, windows-8, midtown-madness-2

There's this old game, called *Midtown Madness 2* (2000), that I love playing. It requires DirectX v7.0a. I also have a laptop. On this laptop, when I play the game on Windows 7, it works perfectly. In Windows 8, it lags everywhere, even in the menus.

I read somewhere that Microsoft dropped hardware acceleration support for DirectX 7.x in Windows 8. Is it possible to get the game working on Windows 8? I really don't like Windows 7 (long story), and this game is the only thing that's holding me back from upgrading.

Comment: Its not possible for Microsoft to "drop" support for hardware acceleration.  That just isn't how DirectX works.

Answer (score 1):

The [possible solution](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Type=Software&Name=Microsoft%20Midtown%20Madness%202&ModelOrVersion=2&Vendor=Microsoft&Locale=&LastSearchTerm=&BreadcrumbPath=&TempOsid=Windows%208.1) is to disable Hyper-V (Windows 8 component) which is used for Microsoft virtual machines.

To disable Hyper-V go to `Control Panel` - `Programs and Features` - `Turn Windows Components On or Off`, then uncheck `Hyper-V` and click OK.

As other option I would try to turn On or Off V-Sync in the game video or in video driver settings, there is somewhat similar problem with Dead Space game on AMD videocards which fixes that way.

Comment: Hey - update. Tried that, but Hyper-V was already turned off.

Comment: @NSDCars5 see update, but I guess that's my last possible guess what to try on that.

Comment: Thanks. Last possible guess didn't work, sadly. So it's either a VM now or a dual-boot.